# React - App component not updating theme correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, themes, styled-components

I am trying to implement a theme toggle feature in my React application using the ThemeContext and the useState hook. I have created two themes, "light" and "dark", and a ThemeContext object to make the current theme available to all child components. I have also created an App component that wraps the provided component with the ThemeContext.Provider and a toggle button to switch between the two themes.

The problem is that, when I click the toggle button, the theme is not changing correctly. The button click seems to be registered, but the theme is not updating. I have tried different approaches, but I can't seem to find the issue.

Here is my _app.js file:
`
import { ThemeContext } from '../behaviour/context';
import { useState } from 'react';

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState(ThemeContext.themes.light);

function toggleTheme() {
  setCurrentTheme(currentTheme === ThemeContext.themes.light ? ThemeContext.themes.dark     :ThemeContext.themes.light);
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={currentTheme}>
      <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Toggle theme</button>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`

And here is my context.js file defined inside of a folder named behaviour:
`
import { createContext } from 'react';

```
export const themes = {
  light: {
    background: 'white',
    text: 'black'
  },
  dark: {
    background: 'black',
    text: 'white'
  }
};

export const ThemeContext = createContext(themes);
```

`

Please let me know if you see anything wrong with my code or if you have any suggestions for how to fix this issue.
I tried to use createGlobalStyle from styled-components but I confused myself so I removed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, implementing Dark-Light-Mode with localStrorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591752/react-implementing-dark-light-mode-with-localstrorage)

Comment: @yousoumar, I resolved the issue, it was caused due to my lack of understanding of the createGlobalStyle concept. Thankyou for your help